# Poor quality screen at 1920x1080 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display-resolution

When I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 it launched with the nouveau driver rather than the Nvidia one and at 1920x1080. If I switched to the Nvidia driver I could only get a resolution of 1600x1200. I think this is because, for whatever reason, the system when using an Nvidia driver does not pick up the EDID (monitor characteristics) from the monitor (an Acer K222HQL). The cure as I found on Linux Mint 18.3 is to save the EDID when using the nouveau driver and use it as a custom EDID when using the Nvidia driver with the monitors actual vert and horizontal sync settings. So far so good.

When I had done this the available resolutions increased and I can get 1920x1080 but the image is very poor in Ubuntu 18.04. The image is slightly out of focus and there is color fringing on text and edges. Using LM18.3 I did not have this problem but Ubuntu 18.04 is a newer system than the one LM18.3 is based on and probably leads to different issues.

Has anyone else had any problem similar to this and can anyone suggest a possible solution?